# How to identify api version of an application or service

Tags: api, curl

Newbie to API consumption and wasted hours trying to consume a REST 2.0 API resource to find out that we are using 1.0 API. Want to avoid this mistake in the future and looking for ways to identify API version that’s consumable.

In this case it’s an on-prem bitbucket server. Been searching if there’s any default ways to identify an applications API version without success.

Is there a good and easy way to identify which api version an application is accessible by?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is a *general* way APIs commonly use to communicate their versions

Comment: Then How do I identify api path specifically? Can I curl the website or something to indenting which version the api is ?

Comment: @Antonow297296. No, like I said, there is no general way to do this. There might be specific ways for specific APIs, but this will be dependent on the API and how they communicate versions.